# Calculating morphometric properties

Tags: graphs-and-networks, graphics3d

Is it possible to calculate segment length, segment diameter and branch angles for three dimensional geometry. Geometry contains vertex points and polygon surfaces as

```
  file = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6RYT.png";
  Import[file, "Graphics3D"]
```

[image]

```
  data = Import[file, "VertexData"];
  polysurface = Import[file, "PolygonData"];
  Graphics3D[Point@data]
```

Comment: Six hours ago you asked a question. In the answers to that question you can find at least two different ways to calculate segment lengths and angles. Could you please specify why this question is different?

Comment: @belisarius: That question was for 2d image, which had center line in the image. This question have 3d geometry and it doesnt have flat plane 2d image, I think this is entirely a different problem.

Comment: One possible approach is to `Rasterize` the 3D graphics with various rotations applied, and use the thinning and morphological operations you already have for 2D. It should be relatively easy to solve for the 3D vertex positions from a set of known rotations and corresponding 2D vertex positions. I guess the tricky part will be to identify the same vertices in multiple views. Sorry, I don't have time to write any actual code...

Comment: @Jay, just to let you know I had a go using my idea, and there were more complications than I realised! In particular, the number of vertices found by `MorphologicalGraph` varies with the rotation of the object. It's an interesting problem.

Comment: @SimonWoods see my (partial) answer. Perhaps inspires you some idea on how to get there

Comment: @belisarius, it looks like you're most of the way there already!

Comment: @SimonWoods I do now :)

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about the context of this problem? I am curious what is this all about. Seems interesting.

Comment: The dropbox file link is broked...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I decided to post another answer for several reasons:

- I made up a full working contraption by using another approach
- The previous answer could be useful for others, so I prefer to leave
  it there
- Both answers are quite long, and having both in one post will clutter
  it

That said, **the plan is the following:**

1. Collapse the points as before, pre-clustering them over an skeleton
2. Calculate real clusters and collapse each point to the Center of
   Mass of its cluster
3. From the polygon's description, get the surviving lines that form a
   3D skeleton for the figure
4. Find the branch points in the skeleton, and the incoming lines to
   each branch point
5. Calculate the angles

**Limitations/ To-dos:**

1. The method used is purely metric, without regarding the topological
   characteristics of the body. It works very well here, because the
   branches are not nearby parallel structures. May fail for tangled
   things
2. There are two iterative loops that (perhaps) will be converted to
   something more Mathematica-ish if I find time/momentum and a way to
   do it.

**Note:** As the code here will be interspersed with graphics and comments, you may like to download a fully functional .nb in only one step. For that, execute the following and you'll get a new notebook ready for running, downloaded from imgur:

```
NotebookPut@ImportString[Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@
TakeWhile[Flatten@ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP8xo.png"],"Byte"],#!=0&],"NB"]
```

Ok. Let's get something done:

```
i = Import["http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68983831/final.vtk", "GraphicsComplex"];
j = i[[1]]; (*Point coordinates*)
(*Number of Nearest neighbors to take in account for collapsing the 3D structure*)
nn = 40;

j1 = j/2; (*some initial value for the iteration stopping test*)
(*Search for a quasi fixed point by moving towards the CoM of NN*)
While[Total[Abs[j1 - j], -1] > Length@j/100,
 j1 = j;
 (j[[#]] = Mean[Nearest[j, j[[#]], nn]]) & /@ Range@Length@j]
jp = j; (*To preserve j for later use*)
(*Show our proto-clusters*)
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.1], EdgeForm[None], 
                GraphicsComplex[i[[1]], i[[2]]]}], ListPointPlot3D[j]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we have a nice arrangement of *all our points* over one skeleton, we need to proceed further and collapse each cluster to its Center of Mass, to reduce the number of points drastically and allow us to have segments linking those points.
Sorry, iteration follows:

```
(*Now collpse every point to its corresponding CoM*)
(*maxdist is an estimation of a safe intercluster distance*)
maxdist = Mean[EuclideanDistance[j[[#]], First@Complement[
                                              Nearest[j, j[[#]], 81], 
                                              Nearest[j, j[[#]], 80]]] & /@ 
                               RandomSample[Range@Length@j, IntegerPart[Length@j/5]]]/2;
h = 0;
agg (*buckets for clusters*) = n = {};
(*Calculate clusters, FindClusters[] doesn't do any good here :( *)
While[j != {},
  h++;
  AppendTo[agg, {First@j}];
  While[j != {} && EuclideanDistance[agg[[h, 1]], 
                                     n = (Nearest[j, agg[[h, 1]], 1][[1]])] < maxdist,
   j = DeleteCases[j, n];
   AppendTo[agg[[h]], n];
   ]
  ];
(*Clusters calculated, collapse each cluster to its mean*)
rules = (Thread[Rule[#, x]] /. x -> Mean[#]) & /@ agg;
j = (jp /. Flatten[rules, 1]);
```

Now we have our points completely collapsed. Lets see what we found:

```
(*A plot showing the lines found*)
rul = Thread[Rule[Range@Length@j, j]];
vl = (i[[2]] /. rul) /. {a_List, b_List, c_List} /; a != b != c ->  Sequence[];
uniLines = Union[Sort /@ Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ vl[[1, 1]], 1]] /. {a_, a_} -> Sequence[];
Graphics3D@Table[{Thick, Hue@RandomReal[], Line@l}, {l, uniLines}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Nice. Now we can explore the endpoints for each segment:

```
Manipulate[Show[
  Graphics3D@{Opacity[.1], EdgeForm[None], GraphicsComplex[i[[1]], i[[2]]]}, 
  Graphics3D@Table[{Hue[o/Length@uniLines], Line@uniLines[[o]]}, {o, 1, Length@uniLines}], 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], Point[Union@Flatten[uniLines, 1]]}], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[uniLines[[w]]]}]
  ], {w, 1, Length@uniLines, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We are almost there, now we identify the branch points and the related lines:

```
(*Now get and process the bifurcation points*)
branchPt = First /@ Extract[#, Position[Length /@ #, 3]] &@(Gather@Flatten[uniLines, 1]);
(*Get the incoming lines to each point *)
branchLn = Extract[uniLines, #] &/@ ((Position[uniLines, #] & /@ branchPt)[[All,All,1 ;;1]]);
```

Let's see if we identified our branch points correctly:

```
(*Plot Bifurcations*)
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.1], EdgeForm[None],GraphicsComplex[i[[1]], i[[2]]]}],     
     Graphics3D[Line /@ branchLn],
     Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[branchPt]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we get normalized vectors along the lines, outgoing from each branch point

```
(*Get the normalized vectors at the branch points*)
aux[x_] := Map[# - First@Commonest[Flatten[x, 1]] &, x, {2}]; 
nv = Map[Normalize, ((Select[Flatten[aux[#], 1], # != {0, 0, 0} &]) & /@ branchLn), {2}];
```

Finally we are going to get our desired 9 angles. As you can observe, in all cases the three segments at each branch point are almost coplanar, so the sum of the angles ought to be near 2 Pi. 
We now calculate the angles and verify the coplanarity observation:

```
(*Angles and kind of Coplanarity test*)
(VectorAngle @@@ Subsets[#, {2}]) & /@ nv
Total /@ ((VectorAngle @@@ Subsets[#, {2}]) & /@ nv)

(* Angles: {{2.0326, 2.54025, 1.70803}, 
            {1.71701, 2.4161, 2.14805}, 
            {2.14213, 1.98282, 2.158}}*)

(* Coplanarity test (Very near 2 Pi): {6.28087, 6.28115, 6.28295} *)
```

Comment: @Jay Nope. In radians

Comment: Great effort, +1 ;-)

Comment: _To the future visitors who might face a problem while running the codes_: for some unknown reasons, the `Uncompress` function might not work as expected. So you have to split the code in two parts. i.e. `str = FromCharacterCode@TakeWhile[Flatten@ImageData[Import[Import@"the-encoded-picture.png","Byte"],#!=0&]    `  and then concatenate the string with one or maybe two zeros, like this: `NotebookPut@ImportString[Uncompress[str<>"0"], "NB"]`

Answer (score 5):

Not a full answer, but gotta something and perhaps it's useful so someone else can help to finish.

The idea is trying to get a skeleton by collapsing the points to the mass center of a group of nearest neighbors. Like this:

```
file = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68983831/final.vtk";
i = Import[file, "GraphicsComplex"];
j = i[[1]];
k = 1 ;(*A parm. In this set up we collapse immediately*)
iter = 4; (*Number of iterations*)
nn = 40; (*Nearest neighbors to take in account*)

(* Apply elastic pressure *)
For[h = 1, h <= iter, h++,
 For[s = 1, s <= Length@j, s++,
  j[[s]] = (Mean[Nearest[j, j[[s]], nn]]) - j[[s]] (1 - k)]]   

(*Show*)
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.1], EdgeForm[None], 
GraphicsComplex[i[[1]], i[[2]]]}], ListPointPlot3D[j]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we have a useless set of scattered points. But not so useless if you remember that they were originally part of polygons. So:

```
Graphics3D@GraphicsComplex[j, i[[2]]]
```

And now we have a nice alien creature:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think if one can figure out which sides of the triangles to keep, and which ones to discard, then we can replace polygons by lines. After that, an intelligent way to take means on those lines can get us somewhere ...

My 2 cents.

**Edit**

One step further, getting rid of some polygons:

```
rul = Thread[Rule[Range@Length@j, j]];
vl = i[[2]] /. rul /. Polygon -> List; (*Polygons as vertices*)

herons[{a_, b_, c_}] := Module[{n, s}, (*Heron's area formula*)
  n = Norm /@ {a - b, b - c, c - a};
  s = Total@n/2;
  Return[Sqrt[s (s - n[[1]]) (s - n[[2]]) (s - n[[3]])]]
  ]
(*Get rid of fat triangles*)
Graphics3D[{Polygon@Select[vl[[1, 1]], herons[#] < 1/100 &], 
  Opacity[.1], EdgeForm[None], GraphicsComplex[i[[1]], i[[2]]]}]
```

[image]

Our alien is getting thinner

**Edit 2**

Getting rid of the polygons, going to lines.

```
(*discard the big area polygons as before*)
ps = Select[vl[[1, 1]], herons[#] < 1/100 &];
(*get the lines of those polygons*)
lines = Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ ps, 1];
(*discard the crunched lines in the skeletonization process*)
selLines = Select[lines, EuclideanDistance[Sequence @@ #] > 1/3 &];
Graphics3D[{Line /@ selLines, Opacity[.1], EdgeForm[None], GraphicsComplex[i[[1]], i[[2]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we have only 1500 lines to deal with.

Comment: plus one thanks