# From iterative to functional

Tags: functional-style

How to write this small piece in a functional way (ie. without state variables)?:

```
test[oldJ_List, newJ_List] := Total[Abs[oldJ - newJ]] > 1;
relax[j_List, x_?NumericQ] := Mean[Nearest[j, x, 4]];

j = Range[100]; (* any numeric list *)
j1 = j/2; (*some initial value for the While[] test to return True*)

While[test[j1, j],
 j1 = j; 
 (j[[#]] = relax[j, j[[#]]]) & /@ Range@Length@j]
```

Comment: `test[]` can also be defined as `test[oldJ_List, newJ_List] := ManhattanDistance[oldJ, newJ] > 1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me first redefine your `relax` to return a list as:

```
Clear@relax1
relax1[j_List, i_Integer] := MapAt[Mean[Nearest[j, #, 4]] &, j, i]
```

Then, the algorithm can be written in a functional way without state variables using `Fold` and `NestWhile` as follows (if I understood your intentions correctly):

```
With[{indx = Range@Length@#}, NestWhile[Fold[relax1[#1, #2] &, #, indx] &, #, test, 2]] &@j
```

Comment: Very nice! thanks!

Comment: BTW. This is the first iterative structure I used in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11206/193). I'm still thinking about the second one

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
fold = Function[{lst},Fold[(ReplacePart[#1, #2 ->relax[#1, #1[[#2]]]]) &, 
  lst,  Range@Length@lst]]; 
fxpnt = FixedPoint[fold, #, SameTest -> (Not[test[#1, #2]] &)] &;
fxpnt@j
```

Comment: nice! Why the `N@`?

Comment: forgot to remove `N` (i was using it to simplify the printed output) ... removed now.

Comment: @belisarius, on second thought (and few limited timing tests with `j=Range[1000]`) it seems that `N` is actually cruical for speed.